# Google Chrome 39 still refuses my SSL website despite I updated httpd-ssl.conf

Tags: google-chrome, poodle-attack, sslv3

Here is my environment : Server RHEL 6.3, Apache 2.2.15 ,Tomcat 6, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips

In order to eliminate the Poodle vulnerability in Google Chrome 39, I’m trying since a couple of days to block SSL 2 and SSL 3 in my config files, but my server is still vulnerable and accept SSL V3.

What I did till now:

1. Add directive `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3` in httpd-ssl.conf
2. Check the syntax of the file with “apachectl configtest”
3. Restart Apache

Google Chrome still show the message

> ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION

As I have another config file named httpd-vhosts.conf where my virtual host pointing to Tomacat is defined, when I tried to add the same directive `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3` inside block , I got the message

> ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, Opera and FireFox did not work more at all.

Is there anything I should check or change? I’ve almost no more hair in my head…